# Why doesn't this org-mode header-arg get applied?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

When I try to run this:

```
** Header name
   :PROPERTIES:
   :header-args: :noweb yes
   :END:

#+NAME: prop_test
#+begin_src sh
  echo "...and it worked!"
#+end_src

#+begin_src sh
  echo "Beginning expansion..."
  <<prop_test>>
#+end_src
```

I get the error `sh: 2: Syntax error: end of file unexpected`.

If I add `:noweb yes` to the code header, it executes as expected. I thought the `:header-args:` property was supposed to do that automatically, but apparently it isn't. I've tried removing the whitespace separating the snippets and (unsurprisingly) it doesn't make a difference. I've tried specifying that the property is for sh (`:header-args:sh:`) but that doesn't do it either. Why doesn't the header-arg get applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the code in the question doesn't work, since it's what's in the [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-arguments-in-Org-mode-properties.html). What does work is the following, which I got from [a different org-mode manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Header-arguments-in-Org-mode-properties.html):

```
* Header name
  :PROPERTIES:
  :noweb: yes
  :END:
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax was changed with Org 8.0. The syntax in your answer is for <8.0. You are probably using your distro's Org which is still 7.something. You can set Orgmode.org as a source for package.el or el-get to stay with the latest org.

For the record, the code in your question yields:

```
1.1 Header name
───────────────

  ┌────
  │ echo "...and it worked!"
  └────

  ┌────
  │ echo "Beginning expansion..."
  │ echo "...and it worked!"
  └────
```

Comment: So, what would the 8.0+ syntax look like?